# What is HP's webOS?

Tags: webos

What is webOS? Is it based on Palm OS, or is it different? What language do developers need to know to develop apps for it?

I've heard it's cross-platform, using JavaScript. Is knowledge of JavaScript all that's needed to develop any type of application? How can I developer native applications for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could build using JavaScript, C, C++

A webcast on webOS by Mitch Allen, CTO of palm

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXS3SQauwPE

Here's from HP themselves...

http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1761&Itemid=26

Comment: Mostly when people refer to the core of WebOS (mojo) there is no C or C++, and it's pure javascript. Of course there are limits to what you can do, then.  So then, you have to build extensions and those are in a native language. I think. Am I right?

Comment: Warren: webOS offers 3 types of apps: pure javascript (Mojo or Enyo apps), PDK apps (native apps written in C/C++), or Hybrid apps which are PDK apps with some js on top.  Hybrid apps are usually the best way to do the coolest stuff from what I've seen.  Here's a video on them:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWg9xFwKGcM

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps start with an overview:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS